# how can I wait for options with a messagebox in vaadin?

Tags: messagebox, vaadin7

I'm little new to Vaadin and web applications. I'm having problems getting the selected option (a simple yes or no) from a `MessageBox` with Vaadin add-on Steinwedel.

I need to wait for the client to say "yes" or "no", then run my code for that option, as in java `JOption`. I have a class for `MessageBox` that returns the option:

```
int option = MessageBox.showDialog (message, title, QUESTION_YES_NO_OPTION);
```

But my code always runs through, even though I have my `MessageBox` opened.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike in a traditional desktop GUI framework such as Swing, with Vaadin you are programming primarily on the server side and listen to events from the client side (browser with user interaction). So, showing a dialog does not block on the server side code because the answer to the (HTTP) request that came from client wouldn't be sent. Instead you should show the dialog and listen to the click events of the dialog buttons.

```
MessageBox
    .createInfo()
    .withCaption("Info")
    .withMessage("Hello World!")
    .withOkButton(() -> System.out.println("Ok pressed."))
    .open();
```

The example is taken from the add-on description. Here they handled the OK-button click with a println.

Comment: Me neither! in that case, when you have more codes after .open(); which depends on the MessageBox but shouldn't get place in the MessageBox(), what should we do? do you have any suggestion? how to stop the code at MessageBox point and then Continue it again!?

Comment: I don't know if I get you right but you can call any code in the lambda in `withOkButton`. For example, you could make a method `doXYZ` containing all the code that should be done _after_ the OK button was pressed by user and then reference this method like `withOkButton(this::doXYZ)`. You can't actually "stop the code at MessageBox".