# Vaadin MessageBox

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin `MessageBox`, the problem that I have which is logic is that the code after `MessageBox` runs immediately and doesn't wait for your `MessageBox` answer. I tried to pack my code in a function which returns a boolean. But it seems impossible to do it with `MessageBox()`, here is a sample of what I want to do:

```
private boolean Delete(){
   return true;
}

private boolean IsDone(){
    MessageBox
    .createQuestion()
    .withCaption("Delete")
    .withMessage("Are you sure?")
    .withYesButton(()-> return Delete()) //here is where i have problem 
    .withNoButton(()-> {})
    .open();
}
```

I tried also,

```
    .withYesButton(()-> {return Delete();})
```

it seems to work like this but without `return true;`

```
.withYesButton(()-> {if(Delete){
    return true; //doesn't work!
    System.out.printLn("Works!"); // works :-?
}})
```

anyone know this situation or has any idea?

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774714/how-can-i-wait-for-options-with-a-messagebox-in-vaadin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I wait for options with a messagebox in vaadin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774714/how-can-i-wait-for-options-with-a-messagebox-in-vaadin)

Comment: @andré-schild  it's not the same Question, I already read that Topic, my Question is if I can do any tricks or something here.

Comment: It is a duplicate in the sense that your code won't stop when the Dialog is displayed, it continues to run. Do you will have to put your delete code in a separate function and call it from the event listener.

Comment: I already tried to define a public variable and instead of using return, using an If statement and changing that public variable. then afterward I used a while statement with the exception, if the variable changed, to make a short pause, but it's not a good way.

Comment: Please show you main code, where you open the dialog and what you wish to do after Confirm->Yes

Comment: you're right, i saw the problem, i'm trying to renew the topic again

Answer (score 1):

Actions that require user interaction are not "stopping" code execution. You need to organize your code so that it continues in handlers for yes and no buttons. So make sure that your "flow" stops to showing confirmation box and continues after yes or no has been answered.

```
private void IsDone(){
    MessageBox
    .createQuestion()
    .withCaption("Delete")
    .withMessage("Are you sure?")
    .withYesButton(()-> onUserAnsweredYes())
    .withNoButton(()-> onUserAnsweredNo())
    .open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `withYesButton` method gets a `Runnable` that is gonna be executed when the user press the yes button. Let's see for a moment the implementation of `Runnable`:

```
public interface Runnable {
    void run();
```

}

As you see, `run` returns `void`, so you cannot return any value, like `true`. Instead, you must **provide the code you use to delete** anything you want, like:

```
MessageBox
.createQuestion()
.withCaption("Delete")
.withMessage("Are you sure?")
.withYesButton(()-> codeToDeleteSomething())
.open();
```